# Error #1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s) En una consulta basica

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la isguiente consulta:

```
SELECT (C.id_marca, C.modelo, C.flash, C.precio_renta) FROM camaras C 
        INNER JOIN marcas M ON C.id_marca = M.id_marca 
        WHERE M.nombre_marca = 'LEICA' 
        AND C.modelo = 'M7' 
        AND C.flash = 1
        AND C.precio_renta = 1500
```

y el resultado que me arroja es

> consulta SQL: Documentación
>
> ## 1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)

ademas me reescribe mi código y hace un agregado a la ultima linea, aquí dicha linea:

```
AND C.precio_renta = 1500 LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: Simplemente quita el paréntesis que encierra a las columnas en el `SELECT`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te lo explico como lo entendí:

- Cuando haces uso de los paréntesis, estas indicando requerir una sola columna, por ejemplo si tratas de renombrar el nombre de esta por otra.

ejemplo:

```
SELECT (nameUser) AS NombreUsuario FROM usuarios;
```

- O cuando estás trabajando con una función de agregación como `SUM`

ejemplo:

```
SELECT SUM(precios) as Total FROM productos;
```

Entonces una forma de mantener los paréntesis aunque no veo el para que sería:

```
SELECT (C.id_marca), (C.modelo), (C.flash), (C.precio_renta) FROM camaras C 
        INNER JOIN marcas M ON C.id_marca = M.id_marca 
        WHERE M.nombre_marca = 'LEICA' 
        AND C.modelo = 'M7' 
        AND C.flash = 1
        AND C.precio_renta = 1500
```

Si planeas dejarlo de este último modo; entonces recomiendo hacer uso de la sintaxis `AS` para renombrar a la columna como te mostré mas arriba.

> De otro modo el error lo que nos indica es que los paréntesis solo esperaban el valor de nombre de una sola columna y en su lugar recibió múltiples de ellos.

Comment: muchas gracias desconocia que los parentesis indicaran algo en especifico, crei que solamente separaban partes de codigo de otras

Answer (score 2):

Prueba lo siguiente, tenias unos () en el SELECT, por eso tenias el error.

```
SELECT C.id_marca, C.modelo, C.flash, C.precio_renta FROM camaras C 
        INNER JOIN marcas M ON C.id_marca = M.id_marca 
        WHERE M.nombre_marca = 'LEICA' 
        AND C.modelo = 'M7' 
        AND C.flash = 1
        AND C.precio_renta = 1500
```

Comment: Seguro que pusieron un negativo en tu respuesta, porque es lo que llamamos solo codigo. Pusiste la solucion, pero no explicaste el porque. Aunque sea basico, explica porque se da el problema y cual es la solucion. mira [answeR]