# Error 1241 operando debe tener una columna al crear función en MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente función y cuando la voy a ejecutar sale:

> error 1241 operando debe tener una columna.

```
Delimiter//
Create function ordpacientes ()
Returns varchar(60)
Begin
    Return (select * from pacientes order by pacApellidos)
End
//
```

Comment: En lugar de `select * `  debes poner `select laColumnaQueQuieresObtener`

Comment: [Acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285868/error-1241-operando-debe-tener-1-columnas-en-una-consulta-basica) te dejo el link a 2 respuestas a un problema muy similar al tuyo.